# How to keep track of user data

Tags: php, oop, session

What is the best way in OOP, SESSIONS, and User Accounts to keep track of user information to use throughout a website. (ex. Stack Overflow, Facebook, Google, YouTube, etc.)

I was thinking that once a user logs in you could assign all the information to the session array. For an example:

> $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['roles'].

Then in OOP you could do:

> $foo->getUserId(), $foo->getAge($user_id), etc.

I guess my question is what is the best way to handle information to use for dynamic content across a webpage that is based on the user? (ex. User Profile, Age, Join Date, etc.). Should I only store a SESSION variable of the user_id, then use the user_id to fetch the information I want?

Comment: If it's info that won't change through the whole session then query it once and save it. Otherwise you risk it getting stale and having conflicting values.

Comment: I would only store the user_id in the session and retrieve everything else from the database. If you ask for something which is OOP you should try an orm like doctrine.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main advantages of using OOP principals is that everything becomes an object, with its own properties.

Assuming you've already handled the login process, you'd be better to use their session_id() as an identifier in some way, lookup their user ID, and then return a new object from a User class. Here's a sample:

```
class User
{
    public $forename;
    public $surname;
    public $google;
    ...

    function __construct($id)
    {
        // Get the record from the DB and assign thevalues as follows:
        $this->forename = $dbobject->forename;
        $this->surname = $dbobject->surname;
        $this->google = $dbobject->google;
    }
}
```

You then need to create the User object, and you could assign it as the currently logged in user:

```
$logged_in = new User($id);
```

Thereafter, each property can be accessed using `$logged_in->forename`.

Comment: Take SO's system for an example. How do they go about using OOP to fetch user data. Examples are reputation, profile info, related questions, posts, and answers? Do you just use the stored session id for the user id to fetch the related information?

Comment: Yes. Everything about a user should be stored in a DB. Once a user logs in, you map their session_id to the relevant user ID. Then you can run the constructor as I have shown, and pull through what you need.

Comment: if you must, you can store a serialize version of the object inside `$_SESSION['user']` but that defeats the reason for using sessions. the way BenM showed is the best way to do it, instantiate when the ID exists, if you are going to use the class

Answer (score 0):

You would want to minimize the data you would store in $_SESSION[].

I'm not sure if you can do classes or structs in PHP, but you probably want to create an object of User that has the properties username, user id, roles (array), at minimum. You may add other information that you know will be displayed on every page. This way, you would only have one item in the $_SESSION[] for the user.

As long as the user is logged in, you always have $_SESSION['User'], and you would probably want to use the user info to determine which data to display (blog entries, posted videos, etc), and which sections of the page to show/hide depending on that user's roles.